# Update one table from the conditions of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
dateTable

Date                 Revenue
1-1-11                 0.00
2-1-11                10.00
3-1-11                10.00
4-1-11                 0.00
5-1-11                10.00
6-1-11                10.00
7-1-11                 0.00
8-1-11                 0.00
............................
............................

userTable

Date        count
2-1-11       2
4-1-11       3
```

I want to update the revenue of datetable from the data of userTable with the following condition:

> For 2 count the revenue will be
>   updated (by 10.00) twice according to
>   usertable date increase by 2 days.
>
> That is, for date 2-1-11 & count 2 of
>   usertable the revenue of the datetable
>   will be

```
Date:                       Revenue
.......................................
4-1-11(2-1-11+2 days)        0.00+10.00
6-1-11(2-1-11+4 days)       10.00+10.00
.......................................
```

Output:

```
Date                 Revenue
1-1-11                 0.00
2-1-11                10.00
3-1-11                10.00
4-1-11                 0.00+10.00
5-1-11                10.00
6-1-11                10.00+10.00+10.00
7-1-11                 0.00
8-1-11                 0.00+10.00
.............................
..............................
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand the question - 3-1 has a date greater than 4, so what do you expect on that date? Where's the sample row for 12-1?

Comment: The question really makes no sense. Please post an example of the results you want. Help us understand what the input data is and what the query you're using now is. Is your data above the base data or an example of how things should be?

Comment: Please explain the logic better. Why is the `6-1-11` row being updated when it does not appear in `userTable` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server has a very extensive syntax on the `MERGE` statement. You might want to read into that:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

This should give you a "direction" as you requested.

Comment: thanks for your ans.but i have to work with sql server 2005 where merge is not introduced i think.

Comment: OK, that's true. Maybe this article will help you? http://sqlserver-tips.blogspot.com/2006/09/mimicking-merge-statement-in-sql.html